# Retaining the $_GET url in the link when the user returns to the same page.in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, database

When the user reset the password by sending their email id. The mail which they receive, is something like this.

**Email**

```
http://localhost/folder/folder/reset.php?email=foobar@foo.com&hash=07c5807d0d927
```

When the above link is clicked, the user fills the New password and Confirm password. We are getting the email and the has from the url. The code below.

**reset.php**

```
if( isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']) ) {
    $email = $con->escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $hash = $con->escape_string($_GET['hash']);
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'");
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Invalid URL for password reset!";
        header("location: ../error.php");
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Verification failed, try again!";
    header("location: ../error.php");
}

<!-- form goes here -->
```

We are using the code below to check the matching password.

**resetpassword.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
// Make sure the two passwords match
if ( $_POST['newpassword'] == $_POST['confirmpassword'] ) {
    $new_password = password_hash($_POST['newpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    // We get $_POST['email'] and $_POST['hash'] from the hidden input field of reset.php form
    $email = $con->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $hash = $con->escape_string($_POST['hash']);

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_password', hash='$hash' WHERE email='$email'";

    if ( $con->query($sql) ) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Your password has been reset successfully! <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
    header("location: ../success.php");

    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords did not match, try again!";
    header("location: ../reset.php");
}
}
```

Now the problem is here. If the users password did not match they goes to `reset.php` page and when they need to come back to to try again again. When that happens how do we get their `email` and `hash` back.

```
  else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords did not match, try again!";
    header("location: ../reset.php");
}
```

This is what we get, when they come back.
`http://localhost/folder/folder/reset.php`

Comment: Well then add the same GET parameters again in your location header, duh.

Comment: Or just put them into the session when that URL including them as GET parameters is first requested, so that you already have them available there the second time, without the need to send them on a round-trip to the client again.

Comment: yes, just now we thought the SESSION idea to avoid the same url.

Comment: ...or use Ajax to post the form and you don't need to reload the page at all (plus it gives a smoother experience).

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sessions is your best option here.

Currently the code has another problem which you might want to avoid. Your user can go to resetpassword.php page with ANY email and reset the password for that email, which would result in a very unpleasant security issue.

The proper way of doing what you intend to do would be

reset.php

```
<?php

$email = array_key_exists('email', $_GET) && !empty($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : null;
$hash = array_key_exists('hash', $_GET) && !empty($_GET['hash']) ? $_GET['hash'] : null;

session_start();

if( $email !== null && $hash !== null) {
    $email = $con->escape_string($email);
    $hash = $con->escape_string($hash);
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'");

    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Invalid URL for password reset!";
        header("location: ../error.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['reset_email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['reset_hash'] = $hash;
        // do redirect to your new password page or smth
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Verification failed, try again!";
    header("location: ../error.php");
}
```

and resetpassword.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && array_key_exists('reset_email', $_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['reset_email'])) {
// Make sure the two passwords match
    if ( $_POST['newpassword'] == $_POST['confirmpassword'] ) {
        $new_password = password_hash($_POST['newpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        // not sure why you would need to update password reset hash there, so i removed it
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_password' WHERE email='{$_SESSION['reset_email']}'";

        if ( $con->query($sql) ) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Your password has been reset successfully! <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
            $_SESSION['reset_email'] = null;
            $_SESSION['reset_hash'] = null;
            header("location: ../success.php");
        } else {
            // error probably a good thing here (for the user)
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Verification failed, try again!";
            header("location: ../error.php");
        }
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords did not match, try again!";
        header("location: ../reset.php?email={$_SESSION['reset_email']}&hash={$_SESSION['reset_hash']}");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for array_key_exists(); Thanks. We will look into it. Although this is not an answer for the question i asked. But i'll accept it anyway. cheers.